# Parse json in Swift, AnyObject type

Tags: json, parsing, swift

I'm trying to parse a json but I have some difficulties with the data types and notably the AnyObject type + downcasting.

Let's consider the following json (it's an extract of a full json).

```
{  "weather":
   [
      {
         "id":804,
         "main":"Clouds",
         "description":"overcast clouds",
         "icon":"04d"
      }
   ],
}
```

To me, the json can be described as follow :

```
- json: Dictionary of type [String: AnyObject] (or NSDictionary, so = [NSObject, AnyObject] in Xcode 6 b3)
    - "weather": Array of type [AnyObject] (or NSArray)
         - Dictionary of type [String: AnyObject] (or NSDictionary, so = [NSObject, AnyObject] in Xcode 6 b3)
```

My json is of type AnyObject! (I use `JSONObjectWithData` to get the JSON from a URL).

I then want to access the weather Dictionary. Here is the code I wrote.

```
var localError: NSError?
var json: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError)

if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
 if let weatherDictionary = dict["weather"] as? [AnyObject] {
      // Do stuff with the weatherDictionary
    }
}
```

Here is the error I got

```
Playground execution failed: error: <EXPR>:28:56: error: '[AnyObject]' is not a subtype of '(String, AnyObject)'
        if let weatherDictionary = dict["weather"] as? [AnyObject] {
```

I don't understand why dict["weather"] is compared to a subtype of (String, AnyObject) and not AnyObject.

I declared my dictionary as [String: AnyObject], so I i access a value using the String key, I should have an AnyObject, no ?

If I use NSDictionary instead of [String: AnyObject], it works.

If I use NSArray instead of [AnyObject], it works.

```
- The Xcode 6 beta 3 release notes tell that "NSDictionary* is now imported from Objective-C APIs as [NSObject : AnyObject].".
- And the Swift book: "When you bridge from an NSArray object to a Swift array, the resulting array is of type [AnyObject]."
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to force unwrapping the dict["weather"]!.

```
if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
    println(dict)
       if let weatherDictionary = dict["weather"]! as? [AnyObject] {
            println("\nWeather dictionary:\n\n\(weatherDictionary)")
            if let descriptionString = weatherDictionary[0]["description"]! as? String {
                println("\nDescription of the weather is: \(descriptionString)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we should double check for the existence of the first Optional.

```
if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
    for key in ["weather", "traffic"] {
        if let dictValue = dict[key] {
            if let subArray = dictValue as? [AnyObject] {
                println(subArray[0])
            }
        } else {
            println("Key '\(key)' not found")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems the compiler is trying really hard to interpret `dict["weather"]` as a call to `subscript (i: DictionaryIndex<KeyType, ValueType>) -> (KeyType, ValueType) { get }` when you use `[AnyObject]`. But I'm not sure why... You may want to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm also trying to find the technical reason and to understand how swift works. Also, these two solutions seems to be using NSDictionary and NSArray, I would like to use Swift collection types.

Comment: Well, NSJSONSerialization will give you Foundation types anyway, so it's not a huge deal to use those. But this may be a compiler bug.

Comment: I found the issue, I missed the force unwrapping of the dictionary. I edited my question to detail.

Comment: You should add your edit as a separate answer. (You can answer your own questions - this helps the next person who comes along with the same issue.)

Answer (score 38):

This works fine for me in the playground and in the terminal using `env xcrun swift`

UPDATED FOR SWIFT 4 AND CODABLE

Here is a Swift 4 example using the Codable protocol.

```
var jsonStr = "{\"weather\":[{\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"}],}"

struct Weather: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main: String
    let description: String
    let icon: String
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let weather: [Weather]
}

do {
    let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!)
    print(weather)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

UPDATED FOR SWIFT 3.0

I have updated the code for Swift 3 and also showed how to wrap the parsed JSON into objects. Thanks for all the up votes!

```
import Foundation

struct Weather {
    let id: Int
    let main: String
    let description: String
    let icon: String
}

extension Weather {
    init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        guard
            let id = json["id"] as? Int,
            let main = json["main"] as? String,
            let description = json["description"] as? String,
            let icon = json["icon"] as? String
        else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.main = main
        self.description = description
        self.icon = icon
    }
}

var jsonStr = "{\"weather\":[{\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"}],}"

enum JSONParseError: Error {
    case notADictionary
    case missingWeatherObjects
}

var data = jsonStr.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
do {
    var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
    guard let dict = json as? [String: Any] else { throw JSONParseError.notADictionary }
    guard let weatherJSON = dict["weather"] as? [[String: Any]] else { throw JSONParseError.missingWeatherObjects }
    let weather = weatherJSON.flatMap(Weather.init)
    print(weather)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

-- Previous Answer --

```
import Foundation

var jsonStr = "{\"weather\":[{\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"}],}"
var data = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
var localError: NSError?
var json: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &localError)

if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
    if let weather = dict["weather"] as? [AnyObject] {
        for dict2 in weather {
            let id = dict2["id"]
            let main = dict2["main"]
            let description = dict2["description"]
            println(id)
            println(main)
            println(description)
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm still getting up-votes for this answer, I figured I would revisit it for Swift 2.0:

```
import Foundation

var jsonStr = "{\"weather\":[{\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"}],}"
var data = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
do {
    var json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

    if let dict = json as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let weather = dict["weather"] as? [AnyObject] {
            for dict2 in weather {
                let id = dict2["id"] as? Int
                let main = dict2["main"] as? String
                let description = dict2["description"] as? String
                print(id)
                print(main)
                print(description)
            }
        }
    }

}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The biggest difference is that the variable `json` is no longer an optional type and the do/try/catch syntax. I also went ahead and typed `id`, `main`, and `description`.

Comment: That doesn't work if `weather` is a Swift array or dictionary.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz It works perfectly for me. Thanks, Daniel. Your code saved me after three hours trying to load some json data onto a table view! (swift is by far the most difficult (complicated/cumbersome) programming language I've ever developed in until now).

Answer (score 6):

Try:

- https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json

With it you can go like this:

```
let obj:[String:AnyObject] = [
    "array": [JSON.null, false, 0, "", [], [:]],
    "object":[
        "null":   JSON.null,
        "bool":   true,
        "int":    42,
        "double": 3.141592653589793,
        "string": "a α\t弾\n",
        "array":  [],
        "object": [:]
    ],
    "url":"http://blog.livedoor.com/dankogai/"
]

let json = JSON(obj)

json.toString()
json["object"]["null"].asNull       // NSNull()
json["object"]["bool"].asBool       // true
json["object"]["int"].asInt         // 42
json["object"]["double"].asDouble   // 3.141592653589793
json["object"]["string"].asString   // "a α\t弾\n"
json["array"][0].asNull             // NSNull()
json["array"][1].asBool             // false
json["array"][2].asInt              // 0
json["array"][3].asString           // ""
```

Answer (score 4):

Using my library (https://github.com/isair/JSONHelper) you can do this with your *json* variable of type AnyObject:

```
var weathers = [Weather]() // If deserialization fails, JSONHelper just keeps the old value in a non-optional variable. This lets you assign default values like this.

if let jsonDictionary = json as? JSONDictionary { // JSONDictionary is an alias for [String: AnyObject]
  weathers <-- jsonDictionary["weather"]
}
```

Had your array not been under the key "weather", your code would have been just this:

```
var weathers = [Weather]()
weathers <-- json
```

Or if you have a json string in your hands you can just pass it as well, instead of creating a JSON dictionary from the string first. The only setup you need to do is writing a Weather class or struct:

```
struct Weather: Deserializable {
  var id: String?
  var name: String?
  var description: String?
  var icon: String?

  init(data: [String: AnyObject]) {
    id <-- data["id"]
    name <-- data["name"]
    description <-- data["description"]
    icon <-- data["icon"]
  }
}
```