# Whats the best way to parse JSON format in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a project that polls a URL that returns a JSON format values. Any recommendations of whats the best way to parse the result for my iOS app?

Comment: checkout this librery https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire for swift

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse json in Swift, AnyObject type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671249/parse-json-in-swift-anyobject-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also simply parse

```
var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/")!)
var parcedData : NSMutableDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as! NSMutableDictionary
print(parceData)
```

There are many other ways to do it.

You can use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) with [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Snippet With [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)
  .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
    if(error != nil) {
      NSLog("Error: \(error)")
      println(req)
      println(res)
    }
    else {
      NSLog("Success: \(url)")
      var json = JSON(json!)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all there is no such thing as best way. If there was a best way, you will probably heard it or find it among top google hits.

You can make do-it-yourself with [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html). This what Apple provides, and it is merely the fastest and the hardest to use. It's not even that 'hard', it just get's complicated when JSON has manny sub-levels.

What I can recommend you is [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). It had minor(barely noticable in most apps) overhead but it's much more easier to use in Swift. A great example is found on [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial) site.