# Swift 2 Parsing JSON - Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject'

Tags: json, swift2

I've tried following examples for parsing a JSON file (for example an answer to another question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27206145/4040201) but can't get it to work. I'm now getting the error "Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject'" on the "let ... = item["..."] as? String" lines.

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {

    do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.bytes!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        if let searchResults = jsonResult["Search"] as? [AnyObject] {
            for item in searchResults {
                let title = item["Title"] as? String //Error Here
                let type = item["Type"] as? String //Error Here
                let year = item["Year"] as? String //Error Here

                print("Title: \(title) Type: \(type) Year: \(year)")
            }
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("JSON Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

JSON Example:

```
{ "Search": [
    {
    "Title":"Example 1",
    "Year":"2001",
    "Type":"Type1"
    },
    {
    "Title":"Example 2",
    "Year":"2006",
    "Type":"Type1"
    },
    {
    "Title":"Example 3",
    "Year":"1955",
    "Type":"Type1"
    }
]}
```

Comment: can you print jsonResult and show us how it look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {

    do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.bytes!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        if let searchResults = jsonResult["Search"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for item in searchResults {
                let title = item["Title"]
                let type = item["Type"]
                let year = item["Year"]

                print("Title: \(title) Type: \(type) Year: \(year)")
            }
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("JSON Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the if statement doesn't work. The loop is never executed.

Comment: @Daniel, try use `[[String: AnyObject]]` (i fix answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
let title : String
if let titleVal = item["Title"] as? String
{
   title = titleVal
   print(title)
}
```

This will take care of checking whether the `Title` property value is null or not. If it is not null, It will read the value and set to `titleVal` variable.

If you are sure that it will never have a null value, you can use this code

```
let title = item["Title"] as! String
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both and it still won't compile and gives the same error as in my question.