# Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to fetch a JSON response and store the results in a variable. I've had versions of this code work in previous releases of Swift, until the GM version of Xcode 8 was released. I had a look at a few similar posts on StackOverflow: [Swift 2 Parsing JSON - Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324766/swift-2-parsing-json-cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-anyobject?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [JSON Parsing in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155436/json-parsing-in-swift-3).

However, it seems the ideas conveyed there do not apply in this scenario.

How do I correctly parse the JSON reponse in Swift 3? 
Has something changed in the way JSON is read in Swift 3?

Below is the code in question (it can be run in a playground):

```
import Cocoa

let url = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apiKey/37.5673776,122.048951"

if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url as URL) {
        do {
            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .allowFragments)

        //Store response in NSDictionary for easy access
        let dict = parsedData as? NSDictionary

        let currentConditions = "\(dict!["currently"]!)"

        //This produces an error, Type 'Any' has no subscript members
        let currentTemperatureF = ("\(dict!["currently"]!["temperature"]!!)" as NSString).doubleValue

            //Display all current conditions from API
            print(currentConditions)

            //Output the current temperature in Fahrenheit
            print(currentTemperatureF)

        }
        //else throw an error detailing what went wrong
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Details of JSON parsing error:\n \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here is a sample of the results from the API call after `print(currentConditions)`

```
["icon": partly-cloudy-night, "precipProbability": 0, "pressure": 1015.39, "humidity": 0.75, "precipIntensity": 0, "windSpeed": 6.04, "summary": Partly Cloudy, "ozone": 321.13, "temperature": 49.45, "dewPoint": 41.75, "apparentTemperature": 47, "windBearing": 332, "cloudCover": 0.28, "time": 1480846460]
```

Comment: Can you put the sample data that's returned from your API call?

Comment: Yeah, I just added a sample of the results printed after print(currentConditions). Hope it helps.

Comment: Parse json in swift4 using Codable protocol

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52931265/9316566

Answer (score 176, accepted):

First of all **never load data synchronously from a remote URL**, use always asynchronous methods like `URLSession`.

> 'Any' has no subscript members

occurs because the compiler has no idea of what type the intermediate objects are (for example `currently` in `["currently"]!["temperature"]`) and since you are using Foundation collection types like `NSDictionary` the compiler has no idea at all about the type.

Additionally in Swift 3 it's required to inform the compiler about the type of **all** subscripted objects.

**You have to cast the result of the JSON serialization to the actual type.**

This code uses `URLSession` and **exclusively** Swift native types

```
let urlString = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apiKey/37.5673776,122.048951"

let url = URL(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
  if error != nil {
    print(error)
  } else {
    do {

      let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
      let currentConditions = parsedData["currently"] as! [String:Any]

      print(currentConditions)

      let currentTemperatureF = currentConditions["temperature"] as! Double
      print(currentTemperatureF)
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
    }
  }

}.resume()
```

To print all key / value pairs of `currentConditions` you could write

```
 let currentConditions = parsedData["currently"] as! [String:Any]

  for (key, value) in currentConditions {
    print("\(key) - \(value) ")
  }
```

**A note regarding `jsonObject(with data`:**

Many (it seems all) tutorials suggest `.mutableContainers` or `.mutableLeaves` options which is completely nonsense in Swift. The two options are legacy Objective-C options to assign the result to `NSMutable...` objects. In Swift any `var`iable is mutable by default and passing any of those options and assigning the result to a `let` constant has no effect at all. Further most of the implementations are never mutating the deserialized JSON anyway.

The only (rare) option which is useful in Swift is `.allowFragments` which is required if if the JSON root object could be a value type(`String`, `Number`, `Bool` or `null`) rather than one of the collection types (`array` or `dictionary`). But normally omit the `options` parameter which means *No options*.

===========================================================================

## Some general considerations to parse JSON

JSON is a well-arranged text format. It's very easy to read a JSON string. **Read the string carefully**. There are only six different types – two collection types and four value types.

---

The collection types are

- *Array* - JSON: objects in square brackets `[]` - Swift: `[Any]` but in most cases `[[String:Any]]`
- *Dictionary* - JSON: objects in curly braces `{}` - Swift: `[String:Any]`

The value types are

- *String* - JSON: any value in double quotes `"Foo"`, even `"123"`or `"false"` – Swift: `String`
- *Number* - JSON: numeric values **not** in double quotes `123` or `123.0` – Swift: `Int` or `Double`
- *Bool* - JSON: `true` or `false` **not** in double quotes – Swift: `true` or `false`
- *null* - JSON: `null` – Swift: `NSNull`

According to the JSON specification all keys in dictionaries are required to be `String`.

---

**Basically it's always recommeded to use optional bindings to unwrap optionals safely**

If the root object is a dictionary (`{}`) cast the type to `[String:Any]`

```
if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] { ...
```

and retrieve values by keys with (`OneOfSupportedJSONTypes` is either JSON collection or value type as described above.)

```
if let foo = parsedData["foo"] as? OneOfSupportedJSONTypes {
    print(foo)
}
```

---

If the root object is an array (`[]`) cast the type to `[[String:Any]]`

```
if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] { ...
```

and iterate through the array with

```
for item in parsedData {
    print(item)
}
```

If you need an item at specific index check also if the index exists

```
if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]], parsedData.count > 2,
   let item = parsedData[2] as? OneOfSupportedJSONTypes {
      print(item)
    }
}
```

---

In the rare case that the JSON is simply one of the value types – rather than a collection type – you have to pass the `.allowFragments` option and cast the result to the appropriate value type for example

```
if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? String { ...
```

Apple has published a comprehensive article in the Swift Blog: [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

---

===========================================================================

## In Swift 4+ the `Codable` protocol provides a more convenient way to parse JSON directly into structs / classes.

For example the given JSON sample in the question (slightly modified)

```
let jsonString = """
{"icon": "partly-cloudy-night", "precipProbability": 0, "pressure": 1015.39, "humidity": 0.75, "precip_intensity": 0, "wind_speed": 6.04, "summary": "Partly Cloudy", "ozone": 321.13, "temperature": 49.45, "dew_point": 41.75, "apparent_temperature": 47, "wind_bearing": 332, "cloud_cover": 0.28, "time": 1480846460}
"""
```

can be decoded into the struct `Weather`. The Swift types are the same as described above. There are a few additional options:

- Strings representing an `URL` can be decoded directly as `URL`.
- The `time` integer can be decoded as `Date` with the `dateDecodingStrategy` `.secondsSince1970`.
- *snaked_cased* JSON keys can be converted to *camelCase* with the `keyDecodingStrategy` `.convertFromSnakeCase`

---

```
struct Weather: Decodable {
    let icon, summary: String
    let pressure: Double, humidity, windSpeed : Double
    let ozone, temperature, dewPoint, cloudCover: Double
    let precipProbability, precipIntensity, apparentTemperature, windBearing : Int
    let time: Date
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Other Codable sources:

- [Apple: Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)
- [HackingWithSwift: Codable Cheat Sheet](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet)
- [Ray Wenderlich: Encoding and Decoding in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3418439-encoding-and-decoding-in-swift)

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm just curious why the above code does not show visible output when it's run in a playground.

Comment: As mentioned above you need to cast the ambiguous result of `dict!["currently"]!` to a dictionary that the compiler can safely infer the subsequent key subscription.

Comment: The Apple article is pretty cool, but I couldn't get it to run with swift 3 for some reason. It complains about Type [String : Any]? has no subscript members. There was some other issues with it too, but I was able to get around it. Anyone has an example of their code that actually runs?

Comment: @Shades Ask a question and post your code. Most likely your issue is related to unwrapped optionals.

Comment: Can you put the sample data that's returned from your API call?

Comment: It's not **my** API, I used the key in the question. Unfortunately the key has expired meanwhile. Feel free to sign in at `forecast.io` to get your own key.

Comment: Finally, a solution that works. Thanks. Just a note. For Swift 3 I had to use JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers rather than the empty array in the options argument. Otherwise, it crashed.

Comment: @user3286381 `.mutableContainers` is completely useless in Swift with native collection types. The crash might be related to somewhere else.

Comment: both forcing the unwrap to `[String:Any]` or doing an optional bind (as Apple does in the link you provided) make no sense. All this optionality is insane. Nice answer, though, thanks!

Comment: Why is connecting asynchronously so important?

Comment: @MCCCS a synchronous call will block the caller (=app) until the response is received, resulting in an apparently hanging application.

Comment: Thanks for the note about `mutableContainers` A tutorial mentioned it, but did not mentioned WHY (at least from what I recall). Good to know its intention and that it's not needed.

Answer (score 12):

A big change that happened with Xcode 8 Beta 6 for Swift 3 was that id now imports as `Any` rather than `AnyObject`.

This means that `parsedData` is returned as a dictionary of most likely with the type `[Any:Any]`. Without using a debugger I could not tell you exactly what your cast to `NSDictionary` will do but the error you are seeing is because `dict!["currently"]!` has type `Any`

So, how do you solve this? From the way you've referenced it, I assume `dict!["currently"]!` is a dictionary and so you have many options:

First you could do something like this:

```
let currentConditionsDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = dict!["currently"]! as! [String: AnyObject]
```

This will give you a dictionary object that you can then query for values and so you can get your temperature like this:

```
let currentTemperatureF = currentConditionsDictionary["temperature"] as! Double
```

Or if you would prefer you can do it in line:

```
let currentTemperatureF = (dict!["currently"]! as! [String: AnyObject])["temperature"]! as! Double
```

Hopefully this helps, I'm afraid I have not had time to write a sample app to test it.

One final note: the easiest thing to do, might be to simply cast the JSON payload into `[String: AnyObject]` right at the start.

```
let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Comment: `dict!["currently"]! as! [String: String]` will crash

Comment: The point at which it crashed was the ["temperature"]!! and also trying to cast String to NSString - verified the new solution works http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57d3bc683a422409bf36c391

Comment: `[String: String]` cannot work at all because there are a couple of numeric values. It doesn't work in a **Mac** Playground

Comment: @vadian ah, yes I had not noticed those and the swift sandbox helpfully hid them! - Corrected [once again] now (and tested on macOS). Thank you for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 6):

```
let str = "{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"]}"

let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
    if let names = json["names"] as? [String] 
{
        print(names)
}
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Updated** the `isConnectToNetwork-Function` afterwards, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-in-swift-2-ios-9).

I wrote an extra method for it:

```
import SystemConfiguration

func loadingJSON(_ link:String, postString:String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ JSONObject: AnyObject) -> ()) {

    if(isConnectedToNetwork() == false){
        completionHandler("-1" as AnyObject)
        return
    }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: link)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else { // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse , httpStatus.statusCode != 200 { // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        //JSON successfull
        do {
            let parseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                completionHandler(parseJSON as AnyObject)
            });
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)

    return ret
}
```

So now you can easily call this in your app wherever you want

```
loadingJSON("yourDomain.com/login.php", postString:"email=\(userEmail!)&password=\(password!)") { parseJSON in

    if(String(describing: parseJSON) == "-1"){
        print("No Internet")
    } else {

    if let loginSuccessfull = parseJSON["loginSuccessfull"] as? Bool {
        //... do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Marco, what would be best way to add this function in project? in any contorller or model?

Comment: hey, you just add the first method func loadingJSON(...) in an extra swift file or class. After that you are able to call this from every controller in your project

Comment: i did try it , but i love the idea of demonstrating a full solution and also how to use it including the helper method isConnectedToNetwork()
it me the idea of how to implement it probably in good code

Comment: so i just used a new swift-file (left klick on your project tree, new file ..., swift file) and called it jsonhelper.swift. in this file you place the first code, loadingJSON() and isConnectedToNetwork(). after that you can use this two functions in every part of your project. for example in a loginVC, as an action of the login button you're able to use the second code, obviously you have to change the domain, the post string and the paseJson values (parseJSON["loginSuccessfull"]) so they match to your php file

Answer (score 5):

I built [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io#l=swift) exactly for this purpose. Just paste your sample JSON and quicktype generates this type hierarchy for your API data:

```swift
struct Forecast {
    let hourly: Hourly
    let daily: Daily
    let currently: Currently
    let flags: Flags
    let longitude: Double
    let latitude: Double
    let offset: Int
    let timezone: String
}

struct Hourly {
    let icon: String
    let data: [Currently]
    let summary: String
}

struct Daily {
    let icon: String
    let data: [Datum]
    let summary: String
}

struct Datum {
    let precipIntensityMax: Double
    let apparentTemperatureMinTime: Int
    let apparentTemperatureLowTime: Int
    let apparentTemperatureHighTime: Int
    let apparentTemperatureHigh: Double
    let apparentTemperatureLow: Double
    let apparentTemperatureMaxTime: Int
    let apparentTemperatureMax: Double
    let apparentTemperatureMin: Double
    let icon: String
    let dewPoint: Double
    let cloudCover: Double
    let humidity: Double
    let ozone: Double
    let moonPhase: Double
    let precipIntensity: Double
    let temperatureHigh: Double
    let pressure: Double
    let precipProbability: Double
    let precipIntensityMaxTime: Int
    let precipType: String?
    let sunriseTime: Int
    let summary: String
    let sunsetTime: Int
    let temperatureMax: Double
    let time: Int
    let temperatureLow: Double
    let temperatureHighTime: Int
    let temperatureLowTime: Int
    let temperatureMin: Double
    let temperatureMaxTime: Int
    let temperatureMinTime: Int
    let uvIndexTime: Int
    let windGust: Double
    let uvIndex: Int
    let windBearing: Int
    let windGustTime: Int
    let windSpeed: Double
}

struct Currently {
    let precipProbability: Double
    let humidity: Double
    let cloudCover: Double
    let apparentTemperature: Double
    let dewPoint: Double
    let ozone: Double
    let icon: String
    let precipIntensity: Double
    let temperature: Double
    let pressure: Double
    let precipType: String?
    let summary: String
    let uvIndex: Int
    let windGust: Double
    let time: Int
    let windBearing: Int
    let windSpeed: Double
}

struct Flags {
    let sources: [String]
    let isdStations: [String]
    let units: String
}
```

It also generates dependency-free marshaling code to coax the return value of `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` into a `Forecast`, including a convenience constructor that takes a JSON string so you can quickly parse a strongly typed `Forecast` value and access its fields:

```
let forecast = Forecast.from(json: jsonString)!
print(forecast.daily.data[0].windGustTime)
```

You can install quicktype from npm with `npm i -g quicktype` or [use the web UI](https://quicktype.com?l=swift) to get the complete generated code to paste into your playground.

Comment: The links are failing.

Comment: Fantastic time saver! Good job!

Comment: Brilliant tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to solve your problem. So please check out below solution. Hope it will help you.

```
let str = "{\"names\": [\"Bob\", \"Tim\", \"Tina\"]}"
let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
    if let names = json["names"] as? [String] {
        print(names)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the API interaction method. The JSON parsing is changed only in syntax. The main problem is with the way of fetching data. What you are using is a synchronous way of getting data. This doesn't work in every case. What you should be using is an asynchronous way to fetch data. In this way, you have to request data through the API and wait for it to respond with data. You can achieve this with URL session and third party libraries like `Alamofire`. Below is the code for URL Session method.

```
let urlString = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apiKey/37.5673776,122.048951"
let url = URL.init(string: urlString)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error)
    }
    do {
        let Data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
        // Note if your data is coming in Array you should be using [Any]()
        //Now your data is parsed in Data variable and you can use it normally
        let currentConditions = Data["currently"] as! [String:Any]
        print(currentConditions)
        let currentTemperatureF = currentConditions["temperature"] as! Double
        print(currentTemperatureF)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift has a powerful type inference. Lets get rid of "if let" or "guard let" boilerplate and force unwraps using functional approach:

1. Here is our JSON. We can use optional JSON or usual. I'm using optional in our example:

```
let json: Dictionary<String, Any>? = ["current": ["temperature": 10]]
```

2. Helper functions. We need to write them only once and then reuse with any dictionary:

```
/// Curry
public func curry<A, B, C>(_ f: @escaping (A, B) -> C) -> (A) -> (B) -> C {
    return { a in
        { f(a, $0) }
    }
}

/// Function that takes key and optional dictionary and returns optional value
public func extract<Key, Value>(_ key: Key, _ json: Dictionary<Key, Any>?) -> Value? {
    return json.flatMap {
        cast($0[key])
    }
}

/// Function that takes key and return function that takes optional dictionary and returns optional value
public func extract<Key, Value>(_ key: Key) -> (Dictionary<Key, Any>?) -> Value? {
    return curry(extract)(key)
}

/// Precedence group for our operator
precedencegroup RightApplyPrecedence {
    associativity: right
    higherThan: AssignmentPrecedence
    lowerThan: TernaryPrecedence
}

/// Apply. g § f § a === g(f(a))
infix operator § : RightApplyPrecedence
public func §<A, B>(_ f: (A) -> B, _ a: A) -> B {
    return f(a)
}

/// Wrapper around operator "as".
public func cast<A, B>(_ a: A) -> B? {
    return a as? B
}
```

3. And here is our magic - extract the value:

```
let temperature = (extract("temperature") § extract("current") § json) ?? NSNotFound
```

Just one line of code and no force unwraps or manual type casting. This code works in playground, so you can copy and check it. Here is an implementation [on GitHub.](https://github.com/ViacheslavSoroka/SwiftHelpers)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "User":[
      {
        "FirstUser":{
        "name":"John"
        },
       "Information":"XY",
        "SecondUser":{
        "name":"Tom"
      }
     }
   ]
}
```

If I create model using previous json
Using this link [blog]:  http://www.jsoncafe.com to generate Codable structure or Any Format

**Model**

```
import Foundation
struct RootClass : Codable {
    let user : [Users]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user = "User"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        user = try? values?.decodeIfPresent([Users].self, forKey: .user)
    }
}

struct Users : Codable {
    let firstUser : FirstUser?
    let information : String?
    let secondUser : SecondUser?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstUser = "FirstUser"
        case information = "Information"
        case secondUser = "SecondUser"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        firstUser = try? FirstUser(from: decoder)
        information = try? values?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .information)
        secondUser = try? SecondUser(from: decoder)
    }
}
struct SecondUser : Codable {
    let name : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try? values?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
struct FirstUser : Codable {
    let name : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try? values?.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

**Parse**

```
    do {
        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootClass.self, from: data)
        print(res?.user?.first?.firstUser?.name ?? "Yours optional value")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**
Cant fetch data from your api.
Easiest way to parse json is Use `Decodable` protocol. Or `Codable` (`Encodable & Decodable`).
For ex:

```swift
let json = """
{
    "dueDate": {
        "year": 2021,
        "month": 2,
        "day": 17
    }
}
"""

struct WrapperModel: Codable {
    var dueDate: DueDate
}

struct DueDate: Codable {
    var year: Int
    var month: Int
    var day: Int
}

let jsonData = Data(json.utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let model = try decoder.decode(WrapperModel.self, from: jsonData)
    print(model)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2023 | SWIFT 5.1 | Results solution

Data sample:

```
// Codable is important to be able to encode/decode from/to JSON!
struct ConfigCreds: Codable { 
    // some params
}
```

Solution usage sample:

```
var configCreds = ConfigCreds()
var jsonStr: String = ""

// get JSON from Object
configCreds
   .asJson()
   .onSuccess { jsonStr = $0 }
   .onFailure { _ in // any failure code }

// get object of type "ConfigCreds" from JSON
someJsonString
    .decodeFromJson(type: ConfigCreds.self)
    .onSuccess { configCreds = $0 }
    .onFailure { _ in // any failure code }
```

Back-End code:

```
@available(macOS 10.15, *)
public extension Encodable {
    func asJson() -> Result<String, Error>{
        JSONEncoder()
            .try(self)
            .flatMap{ $0.asString() }
    }
}

public extension String {
    func decodeFromJson<T>(type: T.Type) -> Result<T, Error> where T: Decodable {
        self.asData()
            .flatMap { JSONDecoder().try(type, from: $0) }
    }
}

///////////////////////////////
/// HELPERS
//////////////////////////////

@available(macOS 10.15, *)
fileprivate extension JSONEncoder {
    func `try`<T : Encodable>(_ value: T) -> Result<Output, Error> {
        do {
            return .success(try self.encode(value))
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension JSONDecoder {
    func `try`<T: Decodable>(_ t: T.Type, from data: Data) -> Result<T,Error> {
        do {
            return .success(try self.decode(t, from: data))
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension String {
    func asData() -> Result<Data, Error> {
        if let data = self.data(using: .utf8) {
            return .success(data)
        } else {
            return .failure(WTF("can't convert string to data: \(self)"))
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension Data {
    func asString() -> Result<String, Error> {
        if let str = String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) {
            return .success(str)
        } else {
            return .failure(WTF("can't convert Data to string"))
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func WTF(_ msg: String, code: Int = 0) -> Error {
    NSError(code: code, message: msg)
}

internal extension NSError {
    convenience init(code: Int, message: String) {
        let userInfo: [String: String] = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:message]
        self.init(domain: "FTW", code: code, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```