# Trouble Converting Code to Swift 3.0, Type Any Has no Subscript

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I recently converted my code to Swift 3.0 and a number of errors have shown up. I have viewed other related questions to this specific error, but I have not been able to gain an understanding of what is going on/ what is wrong. I am fairly new to Swift so any explanation is appreciated. Attached is a snippet of my code. [image]

Comment: Don;t you think your answer is available in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3

Comment: Write the code here, instead of taking a screenshot and posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnyObject` has become `Any`. You probably want this method changed to return `[String : Any]`. Likely your `cellDescriptors` array should change to `Any` as well; this will have some cascading changes but should get you closer to compiling.