# How to set JSON output into UILabel in Swift 3.0 ?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have these JSON data.

```
(
        {
        email = "b@p.com.my";
        login = ID001;
        pw = 1234;
    },
        {
        email = "p@d.com.my";
        login = ID002;
        pw = 12345;
    }
)
```

Right now, I can only print **myJSON** value in x code output.

**My question is, how to display each JSON into UILabel _email, _login, _pw?**

Someone said that I need to store as variable and set into UILabel but i don't know how to do it. Appreciate if someone can help me on this matters.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var _email: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var _login: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var _pw: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/get.php")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
                return
            }
            else {
                if let content = data {
                    do {
                        let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                        print(myJSON)
                    }
                    catch {}   
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Store your response in one array and from that array just set a value into label

Comment: Parsing your `json` response depends on the printed `myJSON` format.

Comment: not sure how to store it as array and set it into label . I'm a beginner .. still struggle to understand swift 3.0 concept. sorry.

Comment: can you post you complete JSON data ?

Comment: In your Json Data are two entries of email/login/password but you have only one uilabel for each. Which entry do you want to show on screen?

Comment: @UmairAfzal , the json output as above in my question.

Comment: @jboi . i want to show email data into label only . .

Comment: there is no key for array ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal . nope . just the simple json output . i want to show each json data for it each label .

Comment: Still, I see two email entries in the json data but only one one label to show them. Which one do you want to show. Or do you want both in one label somehow concatenated? Please tell us how the outcome should look like.

Comment: @jboi . _email label = ""b@p.com.my"", _login = "ID001",_pw = "1234" .. no need for the second json object ..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
After the block where you print your myJSON, try this:

```
for eachItem in myJSON {
if let emailParsed = eachItem["email"] as? String {
    print(emailParsed)
    _email.text = emailParsed 
} 
}
```

This loop runs between all the dictionaries and 
**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39423764/3921490)** solution could be helpful for you. Please go through it!

Comment: Hi, i tried your link suggestion . It gives me an error "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x10d055d88) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10d056288)."

Comment: @Jamilah did you use tableview for set all UILabel _email, _login, _pw value ?

Comment: Nope . just using simple UILabel . Reason i'm doing this is to understand the concept of JSON Parse in Swift 3.0 . :)

Comment: @Jamilah how many label you declare for display this json response ?

Comment: just three label .. emal, pw and login

Comment: i tried to add for loop inside do statement . it gives me an error "Type AnyObject does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'"

Comment: @Jamilah i suggest you do same thing with tableview and print your whole json data in label so you get idea about this.

Comment: i haven't check it yet . Just need to 'walk before i can run' :) .. i'm a beginner .. still struggle to understand this language

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this one

```
   for i..0 < myJson.count { 
      let object = myJson[i] as AnyObject
      if let emailParsed = myJSON["email"] as? String {
         _email.text = emailParsed 
      }     
   }
```

EDITED

```
for i..0 < myJson.count { 
      let object = myJson[i] as [String : AnyObject]
      if let emailParsed = myJSON["email"] as? String {
         _email.text = emailParsed 
      }     
   }
```

Comment: what exactly you are facing

Comment: problem is i can't view each of the json data in UILabel . an error occurs "Type AnyObject does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'"

Comment: Check the edited Answer, their might be some syntactical error, Because this code run in `Swift3`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple because your json object gives an array of dictionary so first you have to take first object from array and after that you can take the string passing the key

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/get.php")
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) 
             {
             (data, response, error) in
                  if error != nil
                     {
                       print("Error")
                       return
                     }
                  else 
                     {
                       if let content = data 
                          {
                             do {
                                  let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                                 //   print(myJSON)
                                    for data in myJSON
                                    {
                                        let email = data.1["email"] as? String
                                        _email.text = email

                                    }
                                }
                                catch {}   
                          }
                      }
             }
             task.resume()
      }
}
```

For batter option you can use some predefined libraries like swiftyJSON. To get best result.

Comment: check out this @Jamilah

Comment: somehow i did get an error on this line "for data in myJSON" . it says "Type AnyObject does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'"

Comment: just add as! NSArray after myJSON @Jamilah

Comment: error appear on line if let emailParsed. . "Type NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element" (aka 'Any') has no subscript members

Comment: what is the suggestions are there if you write   "data." (it's 0 or 1).