# UITable Won't display. Value type 'FilmsAPITableViewCell' has no member 'movieTitle'

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am getting build errors when trying to display jSON data in Xcode using Swift 3. I am going to copy a portion of my code to this page with hopes you guys can assist me.

I have found similar questions on this site however answers don't seem to help.

```
 class FilmsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    weak var tableView : UITableView!
    var FilmArray = [String]()

    let film_url = "https://www.testing.com/api/resources/films/1"
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath) as! FilmsAPITableViewCell        
        // Adding the right informations
        cell.movieTitle.text = FilmArray[indexPath.row]
        // Returning the cell
        return cell
    }
    // @IBOutlet weak var FilmsView: UITableView!
    //    weak var tableView : UITableView!
    //    var FilmArray = [String]()
    //
    //    let film_url = "https://www.distribber.com/api/resources/films/1"
    //
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tableView = UITableView (frame:view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        self.tableView = tableView

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self


        //        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //            return 1
        //        }
        //            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //                // Getting the right element
        //               //let films = FilmArray[indexPath.row]
        //
        //
        //                // Instantiate a cell
        //                //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "moviecell")
        //                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FilmsAPITableViewCell
        //                //        cell.movieTitle.text = FilmArray[indexPath.row]
        //                // Adding the right informations
        //                cell.movieTitle.text = FilmArray[indexPath.row]
        //                // Returning the cell
        //                return cell
        //        }
        // }

        //}



        let url:URL = URL(string: film_url)!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("740c94c51891c02b64d6c78840b478fe0b02fe2c", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
        request.setValue("Basic YmhlZW0uZW5nckBnbWFpbC5jb206YmgzM20=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        let paramString = ""


        //        for (key, value) in post_data
        //        {
        //            paramString = paramString + (key as! String) + "=" + (value as! String) + "&"
        //        }
        //
        request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
            (
            data, response, error) in

            guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

                return
            }



            let json: Any?

            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

                //  Prasing JSON
                var parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                print(parsedData)
                if let FilmArray = parsedData["films"] as? NSArray {
                    for movieTitle in FilmArray{
                        if let filmDict = movieTitle as? NSDictionary{
                            if let film = filmDict.value(forKey: "title") {
                                self.FilmArray.append(film as! String)
                            }

                            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                             })

                        }
                    }

                }
                print("Hello")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print(self.FilmArray)
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }


            if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
                {
                    //  self.login_session = session_data

                    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                    preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

                    //  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginDone)
                }
            }



        })

        task.resume()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Here is also output from FilmsAPITableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit
```

import UIKit

```
class FilmsAPITableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var movieTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely the class of the custom cell in Interface Builder is not set to `FilmsAPITableViewCell`.

Comment: @vadian Yes it is. Thanks for the feedback. Anything else I should check?

Comment: Can you show `FilmsAPITableViewCell.swift`?

Comment: The `IBOutlet` `movieTitle` is missing in `FilmsAPITableViewCell`. By the way it's nonsensical to use a custom cell with just one text field. It's practically the same as the standard `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @Losiowaty I have added it to original question.

Comment: PS: Your table view won't display anything anyway as long as the block to reload the table view is commented out.

Comment: @vadian which line is that?

Comment: There is only one `reloadData()` in the code.

Comment: @vadian I have updated the code above and it now builds but still won't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why movieTitle is nil is because your custom cell class does not have that label outlet. You need to create a UILabel in your .xib (or storyboard) and create an outlet connection inside your custom cell class.

It also seems like no `self.tableView.reloadData()` exists in your completion block. Try adding that right after the `print("Hello")` line.

P.S. Don't forget to dispatch the reload to the main queue.

Here is also your code which I edited as to get it working:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    let url:URL = URL(string: film_url)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("740c94c51891c02b64d6c78840b478fe0b02fe2c", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
    request.setValue("Basic YmhlZW0uZW5nckBnbWFpbC5jb206YmgzM20=", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
    let paramString = ""

    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

            return
        }



        var json:Any?

        do
        {
            if let existingData = data {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: existingData, options: [])
            }

            //  Prasing JSON
            if let parsedData = json as? [[String:Any]] {
                for dict in parsedData {
                    if let title = dict["title"] as? String {
                        self.FilmArray.append(title)
                    }
                }

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return
        }

        guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
        {
            return
        }

        if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
            {
                //  self.login_session = session_data

                let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

                //  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: self.LoginDone)
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: You are right. I only went off comment you made about reloading the data. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you! I have added the suggestions and it still not working. I will post updated code above

Comment: @KendellRogers I think there are 2 more things you need to do.
The weak tableView property does not look like its an outlet to the tableView in your .xib (or storyboard). Try connecting that. Honestly, I doubt you even need these lines: 
`let tableView = UITableView (frame:view.bounds)
 view.addSubview(tableView)
 self.tableView = tableView`
The outlet should do the work for you.

Comment: @KendellRogers also change the return value of the numberOfRowsInSection to read `return FilmArray.count`

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier mycell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: This means that you have not given the reuse identifier "mycell" to the custom cell in the storyboard. It's under the attributes inspector of your custom cell named "Identifier". The storyboard needs to know the name of the identifier that matches your string in the cellForRowAtIndex.

I have also updated my answer with code for your parsing technique. I ran the project on my XCode and got it to display the film name correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: ! Thank you! Are you still around?

Comment: @KendellRogers Sure