# Error while assigning value from nested NSDictionary to a variable?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary assigned to a variable restaurant from this API.

[API Call](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=44.1680112%2C-93.9675153&radius=1200&type=restaurant&key=AIzaSyBaqf7fNiIr26U7nWbXz5wblqgvjg-vaiY)

I am trying to assign.

```
let restaurantLat = restaurants[indexPath.row]["geometry"]!["location"]!!["lat"] as? String
```

This is showing an error:

> type any has subscript members.

Comment: Split it up in several lines of code to see were it fails. `lat` is not a String btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3)

Comment: When you show errors, show them correctly, as you got them from the compiler. I bet $100 that you didn't get the error that you claim you got ("type any has subscript members"). Actually I bet you got an error message that is the exact opposite of what you say.

Answer (score 0):

Access json output data as below:

```
let restaurantLat = restaurants["results"][indexPath.row]["geometry"]!["location"]!!["lat"] as? String
```

Because **results** key contain list of array.