# Issue in JSONSerialization in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I received data from api hit that is base64 encoded. So i converted it into string and decoded it using extension method.
After this again converted into data using utf8.

```
do{
     let jsonResult = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
     let jsonDecryptedString = jsonResult?.fromBase64()
     let jsonData = jsonDecryptedString?.data(using: .utf8)
  }catch let err{
            print(err)
  }
```

This is my Json String (jsonDecryptedString)

```
{
    'error_Code': '0',
    'error_msg' : 'Valid Request', 
    'Report_list' :
    [
       {
           “ReportID" : "LEGAL-01","ReportRdlName" : "Statement of Suit filed Accounts(Pending for Judgement)","ReportType" :           "1","ReportShortNameEnum" : "SF Pending STMT"
       },
       {
           "ReportID" : "LEGAL-02","ReportRdlName" : "Suit Filed Account during the Month","ReportType" : "1","ReportShortNameEnum" :               "SF During Month"}
       }
   ]
}
```

How to get "Report_list" from it using JSONSerialization

In jsonResult i received

```
"eydlcnJvcl9Db2RlJzogJzAnLCdlcnJvcl9tc2cnIDogJ1ZhbGlkIFJlcXVlc3QnLCAnY2FzZV9saXN0JyA6IFt7IkN1c3RvbWVyTmFtZSIgOiAiTVIgQUJISU5BViBTSEFSTUEiLCJjYXNlX2lkIiA6ICIiLCJBZHZJRCIgOiAibml0ZXNoMTIzIiwiU3VpdFR5cGUiIDogIjEiLCJjYXNlX25hbWUiIDogIlN1aXQgLyBBcHBsaWNhdGlvbiIsInNlc3Npb25fSWQiIDogIjQwOTQ5OTg4OSIsIkJyYW5jaENvZGUiIDogIjA0MDgifV19"
```

In jsonDecryptedString

```
"{\'error_Code\': \'0\',\'error_msg\' : \'Valid Request\', \'case_list\' : [{\"CustomerName\" : \"MR ABHINAV SHARMA\",\"case_id\" : \"\",\"AdvID\" : \"nitesh123\",\"SuitType\" : \"1\",\"case_name\" : \"Suit / Application\",\"session_Id\" : \"409499889\",\"BranchCode\" : \"0408\"}]}"
```

And Error is

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3

Comment: hi Hamish. what is wrong with this question

Comment: Base64 is an encoding, not encryption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3)

Comment: @JAL, First check at your side. I have tried that one also

Answer (score 0):

```
try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any]
```

Comment: it goes to catch block. i did this ->do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }

Comment: Put a break point on each line in the do section and step through and see what the values are as you go along. Try not to cast as [String:Any] and see what you get also.

Comment: Please Check again. I have modified my post and also tried without [String:Any]

Answer (score 0):

Actually its problem with Json that is not in proper formate. 
I replace single quote with double

```
let jsonResult = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
let jsonDecodedString1 = jsonResult?.fromBase64()
let jsonDecodedString2 = jsonDecodedString1?.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with:"\"")
```

Now it works properly.

To print case_list

```
if let data = jsonDecodedString2?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) 
{
    let json = JSON(data: data)

    for item in json["case_list"]
    {
        print(item)
    }            
}
```

Here is the Output

```
 ("0", 
 {
    "CustomerName" : "MR ABHINAV SHARMA",
    "SuitType" : "1",
    "AdvID" : "nitesh123",
    "case_name" : "Suit \/ Application",
    "case_id" : "",
    "BranchCode" : "0408",
    "session_Id" : "738007867"
})
```

Below is correct Json formate

```
let json = "{\"error_Code\": \"0\",\"error_msg\" : \"Valid Request\", \"case_list\" : [{\"CustomerName\" : \"MR ABHINAV SHARMA\",\"case_id\" : \"\",\"AdvID\" : \"nitesh123\",\"SuitType\" : \"1\",\"case_name\" : \"Suit / Application\",\"session_Id\" : \"923137599\",\"BranchCode\" : \"0408\"}]}"
```

Comment: You should fix the JSON format *on the server*, not in the client.