# Swift 3 Type 'Any' has no subscript members error

Tags: swift

here is the bit of code giving me the issue:

```
func loadUrl(_ obj:AnyObject?){

        let urlObj = obj as! NSDictionary
        let urlPath = urlObj["aps"]!["alert"] as! String
        let requestUrl = URL(string: urlPath)
        let request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Tried many of the things posted but none work in my case, any heal is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Simply ask you this: Who told the compiler that the object `urlObj["aps"]` can be used with subscript by writing `["alert"]` after it (ie doing `urlObj["aps"]!["alert"]`) ? No one. That's what the errors means. `urlObj["aps"]` is of type `Any`, and `Any` by defaults have no subscript, so you can do `anAnyObject["aps"]`. Cast it before.

Comment: Please search on your error. This [has been asked many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+type+%27Any%27+has+no+subscript+members).

Comment: FYI - every use of `!` in your code means "crash here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3 the compiler needs to know the types of **all** subscripted objects.

And it's highly recommend to unwrap the optionals safely:

```
func loadUrl(_ obj: Any?) {

    if let urlObj = obj as? [String:Any],
       let aps = urlObj["aps"] as? [String:Any],
       let urlPath = aps["alert"] as? String,
       let requestUrl = URL(string: urlPath) {
          let request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
          webView.loadRequest(request)
     ...
     }
```

Please read also Larme's comment.

Comment: Side note, since you didn't write it, in Swift 3, prefers Swift Dictionaries rather than NSDictionary, and Any rather than AnyObject, no?

Comment: @Larme Thanks, I wrote that already a countless times in countless comments / answers.

Comment: There must be several duplicates for this question. Why post yet another answer?

Comment: @rmaddy Because most of the *code copy-pasters* are already overstrained if the keys and types in the answers are slightly different ;-) And the answer is also a hint how to properly unwrap optionals.

Comment: What about your own [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39423764/1226963)?