# how to parse JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I have JSON code which I need to parse on swift language

```
{
    data =     {
        id = "kUu6AXbbN2tEeCJJ22fdHh";
        name = Ralf;
    };
}
```

and this code which

```
if let myData = data{
    do{
    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData, options: 
JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject}
                    catch{    
                    }
```

In command line I can see my json structure and what I have inside but I can't understand how I can parse it. Can somebody help me please I just start working with swift

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/dankogai/swift2-json) awesome single-filed library. (not affiliated, just love it)

Comment: What is your actual issue? You've posted code that parses the JSON. So what problem do you have?

Comment: Why do you not use a pod, like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
}

            if let myData = data{
                do{
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let data = myJson["data"] as AnyObject? {
                        if let id = data["id"] as! NSString? {
                            print (id)
                        }
                        if let name = data["name"] as! NSString? {
                            print (name)
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch{

                }
                }
```

Comment: What's with all misuse of `AnyObject?` ? Why are you using `NSString`?