# get specific values from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
 print(json)
```

My print statement gave following result :

```
`Result =  [ 
        {
    Friday = 0;
    Monday = 0;
    Saturday = 0;
    Sunday = 0;
    Thursday = 0;
    Tuesday = 0;
    Wednesday = 1;
},
        {
    Friday = 1;
    Monday = 0;
    Saturday = 0;
    Sunday = 0;
    Thursday = 0;
    Tuesday = 0;
    Wednesday = 0;
}]
```

I want to get the days whose value is 1 (In above `JSON` I want Wednesday and Friday)
How to iterate through this `JSON` ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your JSON Valid???Show what have you tried??

Comment: That is not a json data .. Are you sure about the data?

Comment: Please check my updated Question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3)

Comment: Iterate the dictionaries inside the array and further iterate all keys of the dictionary. Now if the value of the key is 1 add that key in another dictionary with a value 1.
Finally print all the keys of the dictionary you created.

Comment: @Milan can you please explain with an example please

Comment: `json.map({$0.value.map({$0.filter{($0.value == 1)}})})`, if JSON is correctly defined as `[String:[[String:Int]]]`. But according to your level of knownledge, I'd go with a simpler approach: Iteration, and it's unclear the structure you want to keep at the end.

Answer (score -1):

First Check your data is valid JSON. if it's then use below looping to get days

```
     var daysList = [String]()

     for dict in Result {
           for values in dict {
              if let days = values.value as? Int,let values.value! == 1 {
                    daysList.append(days)
               }else{
                  //Sometimes 0 and 1 values doesn't casting as? Int.So probably you can try out with Bool
                  if let days = values.value as? Bool,let values.value! == 1 {
                     daysList.append(days)
                  }
               }
            }
        }

print(daysList) // Wednesday,Friday
```

Comment: How to check my data is valid JSON or no?

Comment: @Spurti plz check with online json editor http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: My JSON format is wrong . How to get it in correct format?

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example in objective c:

```
///Parse Json
NSArray *arrResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];

///Iterate data and form a dictionary with days having 1
NSMutableDictionary *dictDays = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary *dictWeek in arrResult) {

    for (NSString *strDay in [dictWeek allKeys]) {

        if ([[dictWeek objectForKey:strDay]intValue] == 1) {

            [dictDays setObject:@1 forKey:strDay];

        }

    }
}

///Print the days having 1
for (NSString *strDay in [dictDays allKeys]) {

    NSLog(@"Day Name: %@",strDay);
}
```

Comment: Who is down voting my answer, have the courage to message here

Comment: Why in Objective-C?  Spurti has the swift tag.

Comment: This is why I specifically mentioned it at the top. Also Spruti should have said if it didn't helped her. She just needed the example.

Comment: So why are you giving me a down vote picking several of of my past topics when in fact I didn't even you a vote up or down?