# How to pasre JSON (dictionary and array) using the new Swift 3 and Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services, alamofire

Can any one suggest and send me sample code for fetching JSON response. Few APIs I am getting data in the form of the `NSDictionary` and few APIs I am getting data in the form of `NSArray`.

This is my API request with **Alamofire**.

```
APIManager.sharedInstance.getTeacherProfileDataFromURL(){(userJson)-> Void in


        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(userJson)
        print("userJson userJson userJson userJson",userJson)

        print("swiftyJsonVar",swiftyJsonVar)
}
```

1)  API WITH JSON ARRAY OF DATA

```
{
    "status": 1,
    “student”: [
        {
            "name": "Sprouse",
            "subject": [
                “english”
            ],
            "personal_email": "",
            "school_email": "cole.sprouse483@demo.in",
            "phone": "9665478544",
            "class_teacher": false,
            "image": "/assets/default_male.png"
        },
        {
            "name": “elen”,
            "subject": [
                "Social Science"
            ],
            "personal_email": "",
            "school_email": "elena.gilbert564@demo.in",
            "phone": "9066260799",
            "class_teacher": false,
            "image": "/assets/default_female.png"
        },
            ],
    "message": "Details fetched successfully."
}
```

2)  ANOTHER API WITH JSON DICTIONARY OF DATA

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "dashboard": {
        "announcement": [
            {
                "title": "Independence Day Celebration",
                "posted_on": "13 August, 2017"
            }
        ],
        "student": {
            "attendance_percent": 100,
            "assignment": [
                {
                    "title": "Alphabets in HINDI",
                    "end_date": "13/09/2017",
                    "subject": "Hindi",
                    "teacher_name": "Bonnie Bennette"
                }
            ],
            "leave_apply": 13
        },
        "image": "/system/images/86/j1f9DiJi_thumb.jpg?1504593436"
    },
    "message": "Details fetched successfully."
}
```

Comment: you can use `SwiftyJSON` for this.

Comment: @NaumanMalik i am using swiftyjson. i am new ti swift . thats why i couldnt able to hadle json data. can you send sample code

Comment: Please read [Correctly parsing JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3/39423764#39423764) to learn how to read a JSON string. It's very easy. There is also sample code how to handle arrays and dictionaries

Comment: @vadian thank you . but i am looking for alamofire req and post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved my issue long back , posting lately this is my answer it may helpful for other thats why i am posting here.
if data is in the form of array.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            TeacherAPIManager.sharedInstance.FetchTeacherStudentAttendanceDataFromURL(){(attendanceJson)-> Void in

                print("observationInfo --",attendanceJson)
                let swiftyAttendanceJsonVar = JSON(attendanceJson)
                let observation = swiftyAttendanceJsonVar["list"].rawString()!
                let jsonData = observation.data(using: .utf8)!
                let array = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])  as! Array< Any>

                for observationVar in array!{
                    let totlDic  = NSMutableDictionary()
                    let dic = observationVar as! Dictionary<String,Any>
```

}
}

if data is in the form of dictionary. just replace this below of line code in above  function array line.

```
let dictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])  as! Dictionary<String, Any>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) **API WITH JSON ARRAY OF DATA**

```
let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(userJson)
let array : [[String : String]] = swiftyJsonVar["student"]
```

This will give you an array of dictionaries or key-values of student.
Further you can get another value from the array like that

```
let name : String = array[0]["name"]
```

2) **ANOTHER API WITH JSON DICTIONARY OF DATA**

```
let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(userJson)
let dictionary : [[String : String]] = swiftyJsonVar["dashboard"]
```

This will give you an array of dictionary or key-value of dashboard.

```
let array : [[String : String]] = dictionary["announcement"]
```

This will give you the array of announcement and next you can get the further values like this

```
let name : array = array[0]["title"]
```

Comment: let array : [[String : String]] = swiftyJsonVar["student"]  i tried to use this one i am getting error ""  cannot subscript the value of type 'json' with an index of type ,string   '""

Comment: Please use your own variable names.

Comment: i am using variable names but it showing that above error

Comment: What is the data type of your JSON variable?