# Reading JSON output in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to read a JSON output from a web app. This output is:

```
[{"group_name":"XYZ","adminof":0}]
```

I have a struct that looks like:

```
struct grouplistStruct{
var group_name : String
var adminof : Any
}
```

The code that I am using is:

```
let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any]
for jsonResult in jsonArray{

          let loc = grouplistStruct(group_name: jsonResult["group_name"], adminof: jsonResult["adminof"])
```

I can see that jsonArray reads the value correctly. Similarly in the for loop, jsonResult is also reading the value correctly

But when I try to assign this value to a Struct variable, it shows an error:

```
Type 'Any' has no subscript members
```

Why is that happening? Sorry I am new to Swift so I am learning all this.

Comment: Try `[[String: Any]]` instead of `[Any]` in this statement `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any]`

Comment: this works but what does this do? Can you throw some light?

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Type+%27Any%27+has+no+subscript+members). This has been asked many, many times before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your json data is an array containing dictionaries like this:

```
[{"group_name":"XYZ","adminof":0}]
```

You are getting the error

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

because you are downcasting the json as an array of `Any`  and in swift `Any` (as the name suggests) represents any type like `Int`, `Double` or `Dictionary of type [String: String]` as you know that `Int` or `Double` can not have subscript like `someInt["subscript"]`

So you need to downcast to this specific type using `[[String: Any]]` .
This represents an array containing the dictionaries of type [String: Any]. This will work because dictionaries can have subscript members e.g `someDict["group_name"]`

Hence you should use `[[String: Any]]` instead of `[Any]` in this statement `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any]`