# I get escape characters from jsonSerialization and cannot decode them in Swift

Tags: json, swift, unicode-escapes

I have a project in swift where I post a URL and get the result in json.
The json reply from the url contains many greek letters and for example instead of "Γ" I get "\U0393".
How I can translate the escape characters in swift?
My code is the following:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.something.that.creates.a.json.array")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let urlContent = data {
            do {
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                print(jsonResult)
            } catch {
                print("Json Serialization error")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Are you really sure you get things like `\U0393` in actual data instead of that simply appearing when viewing the data in the debugger? What do you see if you show the actual string in a label?

Comment: hmm, haven't test it in label. Only on the debugger.

Comment: This is a huge json result and I cannot select only the jsonResult["name"] items. It returns an error Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3

Answer (score 0):

The escape characters where indeed appearing correct as rmaddy wrote. 
But I had to cast the result as [[String : Any]] in order to access the Dictionary inside the array correctly.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.something.that.creates.a.json.array")!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if let urlContent = data {
        do {
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String : Any]]
            print(jsonResult[0]["description"])
        } catch {
            print("Json Serialization error")
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```