# How to get data from Json using Delete method in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I am unable to implement the JSON using `DELETE` method to get data from server. Is this the right way to implement delete method, if not can anyone help me?

Here is my code

```
func deleteWishListItemsDownloadJsonWithURl(deleteApi: String){
        let url = URL(string: deleteApi)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "DELETE"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? String {
                    print(jsonObj)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.tableDetails.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Method seems to correct me. HTTP Method can be  POST, PUT and DELETE". Did you try it using POSTMan? Is it working on Postman?

Comment: @user0246 what is the error?

Comment: it works using postman  but not in code @Waseem

Comment: Ok, are we getting Response data? Can you paste it? Might be it's not proper JSON response.

Comment: here is the error **Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}** @Waseem

Comment: here is the error @TusharSharma

Comment: JSON response is not proper. you can try to create JSON object with option like.. let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: .allowFragments)

Comment: @user0246, edit in error in the question

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the

```
 let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! String
```

with

```
let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
```

Also you can take reference from [Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3)