# Swift 4 Not Parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I have tried many ways to Parse my JSON reply but all I get is "nil"

I have this code

```
let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsitexxxx.com/api/v2?")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "key=333&quantity=44"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                 return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
                }
}
task.resume()
```

The reply I get here is:

```
responseString = {"received":1312312}
```

However if I try to ParseJson, example by adding this to the VC:

```
struct apiReply: Codable {
    let errorReply: String?
    let receivedReply: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case errorReply = "error"
        case receivedReply = "received"
          }
}
```

and this to the button function:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
  let parsedJson = try? JSONDecoder().decode(apiReply.self, from: data)
print(parsedJson)
}
```

all I get is "nil"

Comment: `received` might be a Int? instead of a String?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3)

Comment: **Do not ignore the error with `try?`**. It will tell you clearly what's wrong.