# JSON string parsing in SWIFT

Tags: json, swift

EDITED:
**I ended up asking the vendor to change the implementation of sending the JSON**

---

I want to parse a JSON string into a `Dictionary` using `swift`.

The plist key has the following value:
`"{runid:\"8090\",status_id:\"5\"}"`
and when I convert this into a `String` object, it looks like this `"\"{runid:\\\"8488\\\",testids:[\"7480769\"]}\""`

**Code**

```
let data = theString.data(using: .utf8)
let jsonObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
```

I have already gone through various posts and am not able to use the conventional solution we use in our daily lives.

Following things I already know:

- The keys are not properly formatted in quotes
- This is ideally not structured in the conventional way for parsing.

**NOTE**

- **Important thing to note is that I will not be able to change the format, because this value is coming from a third party vendor.**
- **Another thing to note is that this string is being successfully parsed by the JAVA team in the company**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correctly Parsing JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3)

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Can you read the question again, its parsing unformatted JSON?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this scenario will actually never happen. I ended up asking the vendor to send the JSON value in the standardized format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it covers all cases, but this is a solution using Regular Expression.

It searches for a pattern

- `{` or `,`
- one or more alphanumeric characters
- `:`

and captures the first and second condition. Then it replaces the found match by adding the quotes:

```
let theString = "{runid:\"8090\",status_id:\"5\"}"
let validJSONString = theString.replacingOccurrences(of: "([{,])(\\w+):", with: "$1\"$2\":", options: .regularExpression)
print(validJSONString)
```

Blame the third party vendor for that mess. Things won't change if nobody complains.

Comment: I ended up asking the vendor to change the way they were sending the JSON.. Thanks for the answer though.