Issue with Saving and Loading JSON Playlist in Swift
I’ve written a function to save a playlist to a JSON file locally. However, when I try to parse it later, Xcode reports that the file does not exist at the specified path, even though the file is indeed there. What could be causing this issue?
Here is my code:
   func savePlaylistData(lista: PlayListModel, _ playlistData: [PlaylistGroup: [PlaylistItem]], to filename: String) async throws {
        // Create a temporary dictionary to hold the data with string keys
        var tempDict: [String: [PlaylistItem]] = [:]
        
        // Convert PlaylistGroup keys to string keys
        for (key, value) in playlistData {
            tempDict[key.groupName] = value
        }
        
        // Encode the dictionary to JSON
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted // To make the JSON human-readable
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601 // Ensure dates are encoded properly
        
        // Perform the JSON encoding and file writing in a background thread
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
                do {
                    let jsonData = try encoder.encode(tempDict)
                    
                    // Write the JSON data to a file with .txt extension
                    let fileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename).appendingPathExtension("json")
                    try jsonData.write(to: fileURL)
                    
                    print("Data saved to \(fileURL.path)")
                    continuation.resume()
                    
                    // Update PlayListModel
                    lista.haveFile = true
                    lista.playlistUrl = fileURL.path
                    print("Updated PlayListModel with \(fileURL.path)")
                    
                    // Assuming modelContext is available and properly configured
                    do {
                        self.modelContext.insert(lista)
                        try modelContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print("Failed to save PlayListModel: \(error)")
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
          
        }
    }
    func loadPlaylistData(from url: URL) async throws -> [PlaylistGroup: [PlaylistItem]] {
        // Debugging: Print the URL
        
        
        // Debugging: Check if file exists
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
            print("File exists at \(url.path)")
        } else {
            print("File does not exist at \(url.path)")
            throw NSError(domain: "FileError", code: 404, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "File does not exist at \(url.path)"])
        }
        
        // Debugging: Check file readability
        do {
            let fileAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.path)
            print("File attributes: \(fileAttributes)")
        } catch {
            print("Error getting file attributes: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            throw NSError(domain: "FileError", code: 403, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Cannot read file attributes at \(url.path)"])
        }

        do {
            // Read the JSON data from the file
            print("Reading JSON data from the file at \(url)")
            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            
            // Decode the JSON data into a temporary dictionary with String keys
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601 // Ensure dates are decoded properly
            
            let tempDict: [String: [PlaylistItem]]
            do {
                tempDict = try decoder.decode([String: [PlaylistItem]].self, from: jsonData)
            } catch let decodeError {
                print("Failed to decode JSON data: \(decodeError.localizedDescription)")
                throw decodeError
            }
            
            // Convert the temporary dictionary back to the original format with PlaylistGroup keys
            var playlistData: [PlaylistGroup: [PlaylistItem]] = [:]
            for (key, value) in tempDict {
                let group = PlaylistGroup(groupName: key)
                playlistData[group] = value
            }
            
            return playlistData
        } catch let dataError {
            print("Failed to load and decode the file: \(dataError.localizedDescription)")
            throw dataError
        }
    }
    




try to rewrite to this solution and check if issue is fixed https://stackoverflow.com/a/75944191/4423545. If it is not - possibly you have app sandbox enabled and didn't request access to needed folder. In this case you need to disable sandbox to check the theory

Can you show the full error message you get, and on which line of your code.

Share the logs, but also lista.playlistUrl = fileURL.path might be wrong if it's in your sandbox, always save a relative path, as the Bundle URL might change... Is it iOS or macOS?
