# Swift Json Response Decoding

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Trying to decode a json response from an https call.
Code that is doing the decoding:

```
if let data = responseData, let _ = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 401 {
                print("Not Authorized")
            } else if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let model: [ListResponse] = try! decoder.decode([ListResponse].self, from: data)
                print("Model: \(model)")

            }
        }
    }
```

It just keeps outputting an empty array. I'm obviously missing something can anyone help? I can call the method of the api from PostMan with the same information that I'm passing from Swift and it returns my values. For some reason the parsing of the return json is failing with no errors.

Edit:
Response Data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "numb": "12345",
        "bName": "Test Tester",
        "clDate": "2018-12-31T00:00:00",
        "currSt": "OK",
        "proPerc": 10,
        "prop": "TBD"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "numb": "123456",
        "bName": "Test Tester2",
        "clDate": "2018-12-31T00:00:00",
        "currSt": "OK",
        "proPerc": 20,
        "prop": "TBD"
    }
]
```

Comes down to be an issue with parsing the clDate from above. Only found that error out once I converted the json to a string and tried to parse that. Trying to figure out how to handle date json parsing now.

Comment: where does the data come from? Your code looks good. If the model is an empty array, you should look into your backend service.

Comment: Sorry I add an edit that may explain that. It comes from an API. I can call the same method from postman and it returns values with the same parameters being passed.

Comment: Please post some sample data that you get using postman

Comment: let json = try JSON(data: data); print(json);  Can you print the data? You can check the data if it is empty.

Comment: So, not entirely sure if this is the same as what you asked. What you asked for was throwing me compiler errors so, I did this: 
let JSON = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print("Json: \(JSON)")
returns a blank output

Comment: Can you add the definition of your `ListResponse` object. Also, create a `String` from `data` and print that. Does it have the JSON you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse json in Swift, AnyObject type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671249/parse-json-in-swift-anyobject-type)

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671249/parse-json-in-swift-anyobject-type

Comment: Also not a dupe different issue it comes to be. So I took the JSON converted it to a string. Was getting a mismatch type on the clDate. So I made the clDate an Int. Changed the JSON to represent that. The JSON String parses. I made the date null in my database, but it still fails to parse the response from the WebApi.

Answer (score 1):

Put the below in a playground. The next time you have to do this sort of thing, remember Playgrounds are your friend:

```
struct ListResponse: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let numb: String
    let bName: String
    let clDate: Date
    let currSt: String
    let proPerc: Int
    let prop: String
}

let myDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    return formatter
}()

let text =
"""
[
{
"id": 1,
"numb": "12345",
"bName": "Test Tester",
"clDate": "2018-12-31T00:00:00",
"currSt": "OK",
"proPerc": 10,
"prop": "TBD"
},
{
"id": 2,
"numb": "123456",
"bName": "Test Tester2",
"clDate": "2018-12-31T00:00:00",
"currSt": "OK",
"proPerc": 20,
"prop": "TBD"
}
]
"""
let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(myDateFormatter)
let model: [ListResponse] = try! decoder.decode([ListResponse].self, from: data)
print("Model: \(model)")
```

Comment: does the clDate have to be a string for this to work? Technically it is a DateTime data type from the api.

Comment: I updated to account for the Date. Not only is playground your friend, so is Google: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-codable-with-custom-dates/